# Storing and calling program file data via pickle

Tags: python

I'm trying to save my data to a file via pickle. Whenever I run my program, the data never seems to loads to 'thelist'.

```
import pickle

thelist = []

thelist.append(input('Input: '))

def save_data():
    with open('thelist.data', 'wb') as filehandle:
        pickle.dump(thelist, filehandle)
        print('Data saved.')

def load_prev_data():
    try:
        with open('thelist.data', 'rb') as filehandle:
            thelist = pickle.load(filehandle)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('No data found. Starting new session.')

load_prev_data()
save_data()

print(thelist)
```

I haven't tried JSON, but I'm trying to get an idea of if this would even work. I know the answer is probably staring me in the face, but I'm hoping someone can help. If anyone can point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your code works correctly on my system. What's the problem?

Comment: you are assigning to a local variable in `load_prev_data`, ...*return the data*. Pickle is a red herring, here, just try something like `def load_prev_data(): thelist = [42]` and you'll see the same behavior

Comment: In other words. Add the line `global thelist` as first line in the function `load_prev_data` and it should work

Comment: Thank you, @gelonida! That worked. I had to rearrange the data a bit, too (I'll update the original question). Thanks again!

Comment: why don't you use `return thelist` in `def load_prev_data()` and later use `thelist = load_prev_data()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create local variable `thelist` and you should use `return` to send it outside function

```
def load_data():
    try:
        with open('thelist.data', 'rb') as filehandle:
            data = pickle.load(filehandle)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('No data found. Starting new session.')
        data = []

    return data
```

and

```
thelist = load_data()
```

Similar way you could get list as argument when you save it

```
def save_data(data):
    with open('thelist.data', 'wb') as filehandle:
        pickle.dump(data, filehandle)
        print('Data saved.')
```

and

```
save_data(thelist)
```

---

Full code:

```
import pickle

# --- functions ---

def load_data():
    try:
        with open('thelist.data', 'rb') as filehandle:
            data = pickle.load(filehandle)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('No data found. Starting new session.')
        data = []

    return data

def save_data(data):
    with open('thelist.data', 'wb') as filehandle:
        pickle.dump(data, filehandle)
        print('Data saved.')

# --- main ---

thelist = load_data()

thelist.append(input('Input: '))

print(thelist)

save_data(thelist)
```